# Image is missing while converting docx to pdf using docx4j in Oracle ADF 12.1.2.0

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, oracle-adf, docx4j

I am trying to covert docx file to pdf in java using docx4j library v3.2.1, I've been following the example given [here](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java) . I am able to convert the document successsfully but it's missing the image which I've put in header of my word file.

I tried the same docx file with the webapp of docx4j to convert to PDF [here](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/docx_to_pdf.html?_ga=1.38204579.1052544223.1423139066), and it gives me the expected result with image.

Logs are as below.

```
<Feb 12, 2015 11:27:17 AM IST> <Error> <org.docx4j.model.images.WordXmlPictureE20> <BEA-000000> <pic missing!!> 
<Feb 12, 2015 11:27:17 AM IST> <Error> <org.docx4j.model.images.WordXmlPictureE20> <BEA-000000> <pic missing!!> 
<Feb 12, 2015 11:27:17 AM IST> <Error> <org.docx4j.model.images.WordXmlPictureE20> <BEA-000000> <<ns0:bar xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:ns0="foo" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
   <wp:extent cx="1029307" cy="964975"/>
   <wp:effectExtent l="19050" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
   <wp:docPr id="2" name="Picture 1" descr="user_image.png"/>
   <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
      <a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="true"/>
   </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
   <a:graphic>
      <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
         <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:nvPicPr>
               <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="user_image.png"/>
               <pic:cNvPicPr/>
            </pic:nvPicPr>
            <pic:blipFill>
               <a:blip r:embed="rId1"/>
               <a:stretch>
                  <a:fillRect/>
               </a:stretch>
            </pic:blipFill>
            <pic:spPr>
               <a:xfrm>
                  <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                  <a:ext cx="1029307" cy="964975"/>
               </a:xfrm>
               <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                  <a:avLst/>
               </a:prstGeom>
            </pic:spPr>
         </pic:pic>
      </a:graphicData>
   </a:graphic>
</ns0:bar>> 
<Feb 12, 2015 11:27:17 AM IST> <Error> <org.docx4j.XmlUtils> <BEA-000000> <java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**UPDATE**

I am having a header in my word doc which contains 3X3 table. In that table only second row is filled with data, first and last row are empty. In second row first column in text data, second column contains image and third column is text data. Upon unzipping the docx file I got three header.xml file.

Here by I am attaching header2.xml as it has the data.

**Header2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:hdr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
   <w:tbl>
      <w:tblPr>
         <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid" />
         <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
         <w:tblBorders>
            <w:top w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
            <w:left w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
            <w:bottom w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
            <w:right w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
            <w:insideH w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
            <w:insideV w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
         </w:tblBorders>
         <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" />
      </w:tblPr>
      <w:tblGrid>
         <w:gridCol w:w="3672" />
         <w:gridCol w:w="3672" />
         <w:gridCol w:w="3672" />
      </w:tblGrid>
      <w:tr w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidTr="00412C93">
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
      <w:tr w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRPr="00FC69E2" w:rsidTr="00412C93">
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:b />
                     <w:i />
                     <w:sz w:val="28" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="28" />
                  </w:rPr>
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93" w:rsidP="00A07653">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
                  <w:spacing w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto" />
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:b />
                     <w:i />
                     <w:sz w:val="28" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="28" />
                  </w:rPr>
               </w:pPr>
               <w:r>
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:b />
                     <w:i />
                     <w:sz w:val="28" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="28" />
                  </w:rPr>
                  <w:t>Left side block</w:t>
               </w:r>
            </w:p>
            <w:p w:rsidR="00412C93" w:rsidRPr="00412C93" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93" w:rsidP="00A07653">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
                  <w:spacing w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto" />
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:sz w:val="18" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="18" />
                  </w:rPr>
               </w:pPr>
               <w:r w:rsidRPr="00412C93">
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:sz w:val="18" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="18" />
                  </w:rPr>
                  <w:t>This is left side block of header</w:t>
               </w:r>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="00412C93" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
               </w:pPr>
               <w:r>
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:noProof />
                  </w:rPr>
                  <w:drawing>
                     <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
                        <wp:extent cx="266020" cy="266020" />
                        <wp:effectExtent l="19050" t="0" r="680" b="0" />
                        <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 0" descr="user_image.png" />
                        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                           <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1" />
                        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                           <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                              <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                                 <pic:nvPicPr>
                                    <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="user_image.png" />
                                    <pic:cNvPicPr />
                                 </pic:nvPicPr>
                                 <pic:blipFill>
                                    <a:blip r:embed="rId1" />
                                    <a:stretch>
                                       <a:fillRect />
                                    </a:stretch>
                                 </pic:blipFill>
                                 <pic:spPr>
                                    <a:xfrm>
                                       <a:off x="0" y="0" />
                                       <a:ext cx="266020" cy="266020" />
                                    </a:xfrm>
                                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                                       <a:avLst />
                                    </a:prstGeom>
                                 </pic:spPr>
                              </pic:pic>
                           </a:graphicData>
                        </a:graphic>
                     </wp:inline>
                  </w:drawing>
               </w:r>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRPr="00FC69E2" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="00FC69E2">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                     <w:b />
                     <w:i />
                     <w:sz w:val="24" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="24" />
                  </w:rPr>
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
            <w:p w:rsidR="00412C93" w:rsidRPr="00412C93" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93" w:rsidP="00412C93">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="HTMLPreformatted" />
                  <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FFFFFF" />
                  <w:bidi />
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                     <w:b />
                     <w:color w:val="212121" />
                     <w:sz w:val="28" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="28" />
                     <w:rtl />
                  </w:rPr>
               </w:pPr>
               <w:r w:rsidRPr="00412C93">
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                     <w:b />
                     <w:color w:val="212121" />
                     <w:sz w:val="28" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="28" />
                     <w:rtl />
                  </w:rPr>
                  <w:t>الصحيح كتلة الجانب</w:t>
               </w:r>
            </w:p>
            <w:p w:rsidR="00412C93" w:rsidRPr="00412C93" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93" w:rsidP="00412C93">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="HTMLPreformatted" />
                  <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FFFFFF" />
                  <w:bidi />
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                     <w:b />
                     <w:color w:val="212121" />
                     <w:sz w:val="28" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="28" />
                  </w:rPr>
               </w:pPr>
               <w:r w:rsidRPr="00412C93">
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                     <w:b />
                     <w:color w:val="212121" />
                     <w:sz w:val="28" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="28" />
                     <w:rtl />
                  </w:rPr>
                  <w:t>هذا هو الحق كتلة الجانب من الرأس</w:t>
               </w:r>
            </w:p>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRPr="00FC69E2" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93" w:rsidP="00412C93">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
                  <w:spacing w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto" />
                  <w:jc w:val="center" />
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                     <w:b />
                     <w:sz w:val="24" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="24" />
                  </w:rPr>
               </w:pPr>
               <w:r w:rsidRPr="00FC69E2">
                  <w:rPr>
                     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                     <w:b />
                     <w:sz w:val="24" />
                     <w:szCs w:val="24" />
                  </w:rPr>
                  <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
               </w:r>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
      <w:tr w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidTr="00412C93">
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
         <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
               <w:tcW w:w="3672" w:type="dxa" />
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
               <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                  <w:tabs>
                     <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
                  </w:tabs>
               </w:pPr>
            </w:p>
         </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
   </w:tbl>
   <w:p w:rsidR="006D65A1" w:rsidRDefault="006D65A1" w:rsidP="006D65A1">
      <w:pPr>
         <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
         <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="9360" />
         </w:tabs>
      </w:pPr>
   </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

**Header1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:hdr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
   <w:p w:rsidR="00412C93" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93">
      <w:pPr>
         <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
      </w:pPr>
   </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

**Header3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:hdr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
   <w:p w:rsidR="00412C93" w:rsidRDefault="00412C93">
      <w:pPr>
         <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
      </w:pPr>
   </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

**[Content_Types].xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
   <Override PartName="/word/footnotes.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footnotes+xml" />
   <Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png" />
   <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" />
   <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/document.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/endnotes.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.endnotes+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/settings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/footer2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footer+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/footer3.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footer+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/footer1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footer+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/header2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/header3.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/fontTable.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/webSettings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/word/header1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml" />
   <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml" />
</Types>
```

**UPDATE**

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: The first line of the log says "pic missing!!", which may be the reason.  Would need to see the XML in the header (you could unzip your docx and post that here).

Comment: @JasonPlutext : Thanks for your time. I've updated question with header.xml. Please leave a comment if anything is not clear.

Comment: WordXmlPictureE20 ought to handle that.  What do the other header parts contain?

Comment: I've updated question with header1.xml, header3.xml and [Content_Types].xml

Comment: Don't know; you'll need to post the docx somewhere for further examination.

Comment: I've uploaded the template at https://www.dropbox.com/s/abm7bow1p86fcra/Template1.docx?dl=0 please have a look. Please note I am integrating it in ADF application.

Comment: I tried your docx through both docx4j's PDF output, and the new commercial renderer.  Both render the image!  (but unfortunately both also look like they may need some tweaking to the Arabic text)

Comment: Thanks JasonPlutext for your efforts, can you please hint me what might be cause in my case which leads to missing image ? I've added all the dependencies from the downloaded zip. I'll update the question with the libraries sequence. Thanks a lot for your time. BTW I'm using the same example mentioned in question.

Comment: one more thing, I am using jDeveloper 12c for an ADF application.

Comment: Hi @JasonPlutext, I tried the solution in Eclipse and it worked fine. but I am not able to run the same code in jDeveloper 12.1.2.0 ADF Application. It gives the same error as I posted in question

Comment: @JasonPlutext I tried to run the sample code from main class in jDeveloper using docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext-3.0.0.jar. but still it misses the image. All text appears fine.

Comment: What happens if you use Glassfish RI JAXB?

Comment: No luck with Glassfish RI JAXB also. Still it gives pic missing error.

Comment: Is the docx you linked to the same docx that the log relates to?  (it says pic missing twice, then shows the xml for a pic, which suggests there is supposed to be more than 1 pic in the docx).  Is the docx a simple file being loaded, or is the pic added by your code?

Comment: Yes this is the same docx that I've attached, I am not adding any picture by code. And I've only 1 picture in docx file.

Comment: @JasonPlutext : finally I ended up hosting my word to pdf application on tomcat server and calling the service from my ADF code. and it works fine. It was an issue of ADF libraries. Thanks for your efforts. One more thing I would like to ask is how can I disable the logging in production environment ? I can see lots of logs in my console.